# Notepad++ as default Windows 7 editor

Tags: notepad++, default

How can I set Notepad++ instead of Windows' Notepad? There's an option in N++ to relate it with given file extension, but how to set N++ for every file extension with no program associated? E.g. if I open xampp's configuration panel and then select httpd.conf, it opens with notepad.

Regards, mopsiok

Answer (score 2):

This is totally off-topic from this site, but check out

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/replace-notepad-with-notepad2/

EDIT: Better yet:
https://superuser.com/questions/474079/how-do-i-set-notepad-as-the-default-editor

Comment: It's a little bit complicated, but thanks, I'll maybe try it.

Comment: Look at the second link; or better yet, check out the other guy's answer. I figured you had already done that and needed an alternative.

Otherwise look for "Default Programs" when you hit your windows key.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

1. Click right on a file you want to open.
2. Choose Notepad++
3. Check "Always use the selected..."

You have to do this for every file extension you want to use Notepad++ with.

Comment: I Don't want to do it manually. I'm looking form something like "when no program is associated, open in Notepad++".

Comment: I don't see how this would work for every file extension, but for your example, you have to do so only once for all *.conf files.

Comment: Sure, but if I try to open other unrecognized file, it'll open with notepad or "open with" window will be shown. I just thought there's a nice way to avoid that.